# type object 'KMeans' has no attribute 'labels_'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ibm-cloud, cluster-analysis, k-means, watson-studio

[image]

I tried to fix using ['KMeans' object has no attribute 'labels_'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49844928/kmeans-object-has-no-attribute-labels)

still I coudn't solve this error. Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

You are confusing **classes** with **instances**.

You want to access the attribute of an instance, but you try to access it at the class where it does not exist.